# How to update a column in a table in SQL Server Management Studio and not introduce duplicates

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Hi this is my first post on stack overflow and I'm hoping to get some help with a query.

I am trying to update a table in SSMS by changing some entries of a column (due to a data entry mistake), however when I try to update the table I am faced with an error like this:

Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'XXXXX'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'XXXXX'. The duplicate key value is XXXXX.

I understand that the error is due to trying to insert duplicate rows but what I also want to do is to sum up on one column which aggregates the data but I am not sure how to do this as I cannot use sum(count) and group by x,y,z.

I have created a sample of data below to illustrate the problem and then what I'd like it to look like.

**Change Apples to Oranges where col3 = 'Large' and col4 = 'USA' and Sum(Count)**

[Sample data before update][image: 1]

[Sample data after update][image: 2]

Sample code for this problem that I have tried:

```
USE database1;   
GO  
UPDATE [dbo].[table]
SET col5 = 'Oranges', Count = sum(Count) 
WHERE col3 = 'Large' and col4 = 'USA'
group by col3, col4, col5;
GO
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions! :)

Comment: The first step is to identify the primary and unique keys for your table. It is FAR better to post a script that contains your DDL and sample data so that everyone can work from the same starting point and avoid confusion. Images are highly discouraged for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write sum(count) that way.
Replace sum(count) with following query

```sql
select sum([count]) from dbo.table where col3 = 'LARGE' and col4 = 'USA'
group by col3, col4, col5;
```

Regarding violation of primary key, you need to remove primary key constraint on which column it is imposed.
You cannot add duplicate values in a Primary key column.

Below is the sample query to remove primary keys from a table

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(512), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @table = N'dbo.table';

SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table 
    + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + name + ';'
    FROM sys.key_constraints
    WHERE [type] = 'PK'
    AND [parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table);

EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for your answer. I have now corrected the sum([count]) aspect of the code but I am still facing the issue with the primary key constraint. It looks like it is telling me that all of the columns are primary keys. Sorry, but do you know what I would need to add to the code to remove the primary keys? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @stevie0101 I have updated my answer how to drop a primary key constraint from a table please check.

Comment: @stevie0101 could you please mark the answer if it is solved your problem?